# Removing convolutional layer filter

Tags: python, python-3.x, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.x

For Python 3.8 and TensorFlow 2.5.0, a simple convolutional layer having 32 filters/kernel maps is defined as:

```
conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
    filters = 32, kernel_size = (3, 3),
    strides = (1, 1), activation = 'relu',
    padding = 'same',
    kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.glorot_normal(),
    use_bias = True
    )
```

This accepts a CIFAR-10 dataset images-

```
# Some random inputs having 3 RGB images of shape (32, 32, 3)-
x = tf.random.normal(mean = 0, stddev = 1, shape = (3, 32, 32, 3))

x.shape
# TensorShape([3, 32, 32, 3])

# Pass input through conv layer-
out = conv(x)

out.shape
# TensorShape([3, 32, 32, 32])
```

The weights and biases are stored in 'conv.weights' which is a Python list variable. They can be accessed as:

```
for param in conv.weights:
    print(f"parameter: {param.shape}")
'''
parameter: (3, 3, 3, 32)
parameter: (32,)
'''
```

In this conv output volume of (3, 3, 3, 32):

1. Filter/kernel map = (3, 3)
2. Input volume = 3 (third index)
3. number of filters/kernel maps applied in current conv layer = 32

According to my understanding, each filter has the volume (3, 3, 3) since each filter extends through the entire input volume. Correct me if I am wrong.

If I need to remove say the first 5 filters from these 32 filters, using the code

```
conv.weights[0][:, :, :, :5] = 0
```

it gives me the error:

> TypeError: 'ResourceVariable' object does not support item assignment

What is the correct way to remove these filters from this conv layer?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "remove"? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Also, conv.weights are not Python lists. They are either numpy arrays, or tensorflow tensors. Can you show which is it please? for example using type(conv.weights)

Comment: @Gulzar I want to perform structured pruning by removing filters within a conv layer.

Comment: @Gulzar If you use ```type(conv.weights)```, it outputs list. ```conv.weights[0]``` and ```conv.weights[1]``` are ```tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops.ResourceVariable```